# Strong Named Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I thought of learning Strong Name , created one example CacheUI project - CacheUI.dll , created strong name by using sn.exe "C:\test.snk" and added this test.snk into Project -> Properties -> Signing -> sign the assembly -> choose a strong name key file. Also generated the public token key. I understand that strong name consists of the assembly's identity—its simple text name, version number, and culture information (if provided)—plus a public key and a digital signature.

1. How can i Reference to Strong-Named Assembly?
2. What is delay sign and how it's helpful for developers ?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference to Strong-Named assembly as normal assemblies. You should include .snk file with the Dll in your project. One benefit of signed assembly is that if you have two versions of same assembly then .Net will automatically refer the latest one.

Delay signing is a process of generating partial signature during development with access only to the public key. The private key can be stored securely and used to apply the final strong name signature just before shipping the project. Delay signing is helpful for organization to ensure that No developer can edit the code and deploy updated (malfunction) code on published environment. It enforces better security.